# PropertyName for PidLidGlobalObjectId and PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId?

Tags: soap, exchangewebservices, mapi

Through trail and error (and Google) I manage to retrieve some meeting extended properties from Exchange Server like this (in my SOAP FindItem call):

```
<typ:AdditionalProperties>
  <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Meeting" PropertyId="3" PropertyType="Binary"/>
  <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Meeting" PropertyId="35" PropertyType="Binary"/>
</typ:AdditionalProperties>
```

I looked up the values 3 and 35 in [MS-OXPROPS] (Exchange Server Protocols Master Property List):
[PidLidGlobalObjectId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203685%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)
[PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee178989%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

But I'm not terribly happy with these two numeric values: without comments the code is not understandable (and what if I mistype the value?).

**What are the PropertyNames for these two so that I can specify `PropertyName` instead of `PropertyId`?**

I tried these without success (no data returns):

```
<typ:AdditionalProperties>
  <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Meeting" PropertyName="PidLidGlobalObjectId" PropertyType="Binary"/>
  <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Meeting" PropertyName="PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId" PropertyType="Binary"/>
</typ:AdditionalProperties>

<typ:AdditionalProperties>
  <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Meeting" PropertyName="GlobalObjectId" PropertyType="Binary"/>
  <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Meeting" PropertyName="CleanGlobalObjectId" PropertyType="Binary"/>
</typ:AdditionalProperties>
```

(Note: for the property sets there is a cross reference for [Commonly used property sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee219487%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx), but I could not find anything for the property names within these sets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815528.aspx those are not even named, so maybe you really cannot use not-number identifiers for them:

> Properties in the range of 0x0001 to 0x7FFF are referred to as tagged properties. Beyond 0x8000 is the range for what is known as named properties, or properties that include a 32-bit globally unique identifier (GUID) and either a Unicode character string or numeric value. Clients can use named properties to customize their property set.

Why not just use `const` values for them in your code? 
Btw, MFCMAPI is a nice tool to find those props without trial-and-error.

Answer (score 1):

Property names are PidLidGlobalObjectId and PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId :-). These are not well known properties, such as Subject. They are just a couple of a gazillion named properties used by Outlook.

Comment: I wrote that using these names returns no data.

Comment: PidLidGlobalObjectId and PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId are symbolic names used in the documentation. EWS does not understand them - there is a limited set of properties that EWS can understand.